# Why is comparision method violating general contract?

Tags: java, comparison, apache-commons-lang3

I can't understand why it's happening on a `compareTo` method using `CompareToBuilder` from Apache Commons Lang 3 and how may I solve it?

The class is as follow:

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.CompareToBuilder;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"segno", "causale", "importi"})
public class SaraReportAggregate implements Comparable<SaraReportAggregate> {

    private final String segno;
    private final String causale;
    private final AggregatoSara importi = new AggregatoSara();

    @Data
    public static class AggregatoSara implements Comparable<AggregatoSara> {

        private long importoTotale;
        private long importoTotaleContanti;
        private long numeroTotaleOperazioni;
        private long numeroTotaleOperazioniContanti;
    
        @Override
        public int compareTo(AggregatoSara other) {
            return new CompareToBuilder()
                    .append(other.importoTotale, this.importoTotale)
                    .append(other.numeroTotaleOperazioni, this.numeroTotaleOperazioni)
                    .append(other.importoTotaleContanti, this.importoTotaleContanti)
                    .append(other.numeroTotaleOperazioniContanti, this.numeroTotaleOperazioniContanti)
                    .toComparison();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SaraReportAggregate other) {
        return new CompareToBuilder()
                .append(this.importi, other.importi)
                .append(this.causale, other.causale)
                .append(this.segno, other.segno)
                .toComparison();
    }
}
```

Calling `Collections#sort(List)` on a list of `SaraReportAggregate` happened to throw

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

What should I do?

Comment: @WJS if you look closely he has 2 Strings and 4 longs, and internally `CompareToBuilder` does the correct thing - I checked. This is weird.

Comment: You didn't override `equals()` on these classes, so probably the contract that's being broken is that `compareTo` and `equals` are not returning consistent results.

Comment: @KevinAnderson why would `equals` (and `hashCode`) matter then you are _comparing_ elements, though?

Comment: It wouldn't, **if you could guarantee that whatever was doing the comparing relied only on `compareTo`**.  How often do you have the luxury of being able to make that guarantee?

Comment: @KevinAnderson by the way, hash and equals are implemented by Lombok's `EqualsAndHashCode`

Comment: but the order is not correct, and the documentation of `ComparisonBuilder` requires it: _The same fields, **in the same order**, should be used in both compareTo(Object) and equals(Object)_

Comment: The CompareToBuilder-based `compareTo` of `SaraReportAggregate` explicily includes a deep compare of the `importi` fields.  Are you certain the Lombok-based `equals` is also deep-comparing `importi'?